fail to use transformers to load model locally
I have used the transformers function to download the whole model
into local directory: /home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/models/moondream2
by the following code:
from huggingface_hub import snapshot_download

# Specify the model ID and revision
model_id = "vikhyatk/moondream2"
revision = "2024-08-26"

# Specify the directory where you want to download the model
download_directory = "/home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/models/moondream2"  # Change this to your desired path

# Download the model files to the specified directory
local_model_path = snapshot_download(repo_id=model_id, revision=revision, local_dir=download_directory)

The model is well-saved in the directory:
when i load the model from local directory by transformers with the following code:
from PIL import Image
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
from pathlib import Path
import os

# Get the parent directory
project_dir = Path(__file__).parent
model_folder_name = 'models/moondream2'
model_dir = str(project_dir/model_folder_name)


# Load the tokenizer and model using the correct model ID
# model_id = "vikhyatk/moondream2"
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(pretrained_model_name_or_path=model_dir, trust_remote_code=True)
model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained( pretrained_model_name_or_path=model_dir, use_safetensors=True, trust_remote_code=True,)

it pops out error message :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/moondream_test.py", line 15, in <module>
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained( pretrained_model_name_or_path=model_dir, use_safetensors=True, trust_remote_code=True,)
  File "/home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 553, in from_pretrained
    model_class = get_class_from_dynamic_module(
  File "/home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/dynamic_module_utils.py", line 552, in get_class_from_dynamic_module
    return get_class_in_module(class_name, final_module, force_reload=force_download)
  File "/home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/dynamic_module_utils.py", line 237, in get_class_in_module
    module_files: List[Path] = [module_file] + sorted(map(Path, get_relative_import_files(module_file)))
  File "/home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/dynamic_module_utils.py", line 128, in get_relative_import_files
    new_imports.extend(get_relative_imports(f))
  File "/home/marcus/Desktop/project/OCR_transformer_practices/.venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/dynamic_module_utils.py", line 97, in get_relative_imports
    with open(module_file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/marcus/.cache/huggingface/modules/transformers_modules/moondream2/fourier_features.py'

How to resolve it?
